# list column with count aggregation function

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Imagine these tables structure

**Organization table**

```
 ===================== 
| id |      name      |
-----+----------------+
| 1  | Organization 1 |
 =====================
```

**Place table**

```
 ================================= 
| id |   name   | organization_id |
-----+----------+-----------------+
| 1  | Place 1  |        1        |
-----+----------+-----------------+
| 2  | Place 2  |        1        |
-----+----------+-----------------+
| 3  | Place 3  |        1        |
 =================================
```

**Profile table**

```
 ============= 
|  username   |
--------------
| 111@xxx.com |
--------------
| 222@xxx.com |
 =============
```

**Visitedplace table**

```
 ================================================ 
| id | place_id | profile_username | visiteddate |
-----+----------+---------------- -+-------------+
| 1  |     1    |   111@xxx.com    | 2017-01-01  |
-----+----------+------------------+-------------+
| 2  |     2    |   111@xxx.com    | 2017-02-01  |
-----+----------+------------------+-------------+
| 3  |     1    |   111@xxx.com    | 2017-01-15  |
 ================================================
```

**Next are sql statments for creating tables and inserting data into it**

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for organization
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "organization";
CREATE TABLE "organization" (
"id" int4 NOT NULL,
"name" varchar(255) COLLATE "default" NOT NULL
) WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
-- ----------------------------
-- Records of organization
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO "organization" VALUES ('1', 'Organization 1');
COMMIT;
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for place
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "place";
CREATE TABLE "place" (
"id" int4 NOT NULL,
"name" varchar(255) COLLATE "default" NOT NULL,
"organization_id" int4 NOT NULL
)WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
-- ----------------------------
-- Records of place
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO "place" VALUES ('1', 'Place 1', '1');
INSERT INTO "place" VALUES ('2', 'Place 2', '1');
INSERT INTO "place" VALUES ('3', 'Place 3', '1');
COMMIT;
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for profile
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "profile";
CREATE TABLE "profile" (
"username" varchar(255) COLLATE "default" NOT NULL
)WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
-- ----------------------------
-- Records of profile
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO "profile" VALUES ('111@xxx.com');
INSERT INTO "profile" VALUES ('222@xx.com');
COMMIT;
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for visitedplace
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "visitedplace";
CREATE TABLE "visitedplace" (
"id" int4 NOT NULL,
"place_id" int4 NOT NULL,
"profile_username" varchar(255) COLLATE "default" NOT NULL,
"visiteddate" date NOT NULL
)WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
-- ----------------------------
-- Records of visitedplace
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO "visitedplace" VALUES ('1', '1', '111@xxx.com', '2017-02-24');
COMMIT;
-- ----------------------------
-- Alter Sequences Owned By 
-- ----------------------------
-- ----------------------------
-- Primary Key structure for table organization
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "organization" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("id");
-- ----------------------------
-- Primary Key structure for table place
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "place" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("id");
-- ----------------------------
-- Primary Key structure for table profile
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "profile" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("username");
-- ----------------------------
-- Primary Key structure for table visitedplace
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "visitedplace" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("id");
-- ----------------------------
-- Foreign Key structure for table "place"
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "place" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("organization_id") REFERENCES
"organization" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
------------------------------
-- Foreign Key structure for table "visitedplace"
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "visitedplace" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("profile_username") REFERENCES    "profile" ("username") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE "visitedplace" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("place_id") REFERENCES "place" ("id

") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

My question is

When i run this next query

```
select profile.username, count(distinct place.id)
    from profile profile 
    left outer join visitedplace visitedplace on profile.username=visitedplace.profile_username 
    inner join place place on visitedplace.place_id=place.id
    where place.organization_id=1
    group by profile.username
```

it return next result

```
 ===================== 
|  username   | count |
 -------------+-------
| 111@xxx.com |   2   |
 =====================
```

**but i am expecting next result**

```
 ===================== 
|  username   | count |
 -------------+-------
| 111@xxx.com |   2   |
 -------------+-------
| 222@xxx.com |   0   |
 =====================
```

So how can i do the query to return me what i am expecting?

I am using Postgres

Comment: Are you really using all those (somewhat) outdated versions?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can't got ur question, can u clarify pls, thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use are using `left join`.  So, all joins should be outer joins (after the first one).  And, you have to be careful about the `where` clause:

```
select p.username, count(distinct place.id)
from profile p left outer join
     visitedplace vp
     on p.username = vp.profile_username left join
     place pl
     on vp.place_id = pl.id and pl.organization_id = 1
group by p.username;
```

If you are not careful, then the outer join turns into an `inner join`.